# What is MCH_SSKPD warning in dmesg?

Tags: kernel, dmesg, drm

While i was reading `dmesg` log just to check that everything is fine, i met

```
[   18.956187] [drm] Wrong MCH_SSKPD value: 0x16040307
[   18.956190] [drm] This can cause pipe underruns and display issues.
[   18.956192] [drm] Please upgrade your BIOS to fix this.
```

Looks that it does not cause problems on my laptop, but what does this message stands for? What can it cause? Where can I read more about `MCH_SSKPD`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dissecting the acronym, I get that MCH stands for 'Memory Controller Hub' with is an older name for the [northbridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northbridge_%28computing%29). This chip is part of your I/O controller hub.

As for SSKPD, there is not much information I can find other than what is in various intel manuals. Here is a snippet from [one of them](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/doc/datasheet/core-i5-600-i3-500-pentium-6000-datasheet-vol-2.pdf):

> **SSKPD — Sticky Scratchpad Data Register**
>
> This register holds 64 writable bits with no functionality behind them. It is for the
>   convenience of BIOS and graphics drivers.

Unfortunately this doesn't give much information on what it is. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scratchpad_memory), scratchpad is "special high-speed memory circuit used to hold small items of data for rapid retrieval."

Another piece of information is the log from the [commit](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=1d7aaa0cfe3d1b5ee23958fce71973e3ae9e52e4) that added the warning:

> drm/i915: detect wrong MCH watermark values
>
> Some early bios versions seem to ship with the wrong tuning values for
>       the MCH, possible resulting in pipe underruns under load. Especially
>       on DP outputs this can lead to black screen, since DP really doesn't
>       like an occasional whack from an underrun.
>
> Unfortunately the registers seem to be locked after boot, so the only
>       thing we can do is politely point out issues and suggest a BIOS
>       upgrade.
>
> Arthur Runyan pointed us at this issue while discussion DP bugs - thus
>       far no confirmation from a bug report yet that it helps. But at least
>       some of my machines here have wrong values, so this might be useful in
>       understanding bug reports.
>
> v2: After a bit more discussion with Art and Ben we've decided to only
>       the check the watermark values, since the OREF ones could be be a
>       notch more aggressive on certain machines.

So seemingly the value of the register has some meaning on some processors. There isn't anything I can find on the internet at this time which explains exactly what could go wrong by it having the wrong value, but I think this gives a good overall idea.

If you really want to dig further, you could email one of the guys who wrote or reviewed the commit.

Comment: Oh, if it is so specific then I think that is not as important as I thought. Well, thank you, I will have a good discussion one day.